# How do I choose the Natural Actor Critic weights dimensions?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, stochastic-processes, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to apply the natural actor critic algorithm described in [Algorithms for Reinforcement Learning](https://sites.ualberta.ca/~szepesva/RLBook.html) by Csaba Szepesvári. I want to use it for the *MountainCar-v0* environment of OpenAI.

As function approximation, I use tile coding right now, but I don't know how to use it along with the actor. If I use a neural network, how should I set the dimensions of the weights such that the update `w = w + beta * theta` and all the rest works? I don't really know yet how `theta` and `w` are related to eachother.